# How to call function every given period on a route

Tags: node.js, function

I need to call a function every given period of time on a route for example my function:

```
function hello(){
 console.log("Hi")
}

app.post("/", (req,res) => {
 res.send("Hi")
 hello()
}
```

**Well, I didn't put all the code in my application, just the part that matters, I need to call the hello function every 5 seconds.  I need to use this method of calling a given function every given period, in my application.**

Comment: what? you want it in your route or run it eveyr 5 second?

Comment: no, I want a function to check the cookie and I need to call it constantly to find out if the cookie exists, if possible take a look at my other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) !

for example: Execute a cron job every 5 Minutes = */5 * * * *

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');
 
var j = schedule.scheduleJob('*/5 * * * *', function(){
  console.log('The answer to life, the universe, and everything!');
});
```

Another solution:
[setInterval](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_args)

```
setInterval(() => {
    // do something every 5 seconds
}, 5000);
```

Comment: I managed with setInterval, but I can call the function that is separate for example:

Comment: try with this setInterval(hello, 5000)

Comment: Erro: Callback must be a function. Received undefined